# Help with vocal sort of sound

Tags: sampling, replication

I am currently working on a track and there is a particular sort of sound that is just begging to be put into it.  I have a pretty good vision of what it sounds like and a good example can be heard on the track supplied.  It is a voice almost a choral effect but now that IM thinking about it, its more of just a plain voice.  You hear it coming in at 1:00 mark and sounds like a pulsing pad, (its not the noise that comes in on the left speaker at 1:16):.  It kind of sits under the track and becomes more prevelant later on and you can actually hear the voice a bit more at 2:14 but I love how it has that pulsing feel throughout the song and becomes almost intoxicating.  Her it alone at 4:05.

I really want to use something like this in my track and have tried looking for some choir stuff and or other vocals but can't seem to be getting what I want.  I preferably need something in D or A  .

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The pulsing is the compressor sidechained from the kick. They're running a lot of the parts through it. I'd say it's just a vocal formant patch.  In Reason, you could try the Malstrom graintable synth and experiment with some of the vocal formants or a sampler looping a vocal sample, starting past the attack, catching the formant and getting an 'ah' or 'oh' sound and looping just that part. Layer it, add some FX and you would be pretty close, I'd think. Good luck with it.

Comment: thanks alot dude.  Im using logic is ther any other plugins I can mess around with that do that.  Seems like the way to go,  should I just look up some granular synthesis?